# Zombie.js is not executing javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zombie.js

I am using zombie.js with node to request a site. But all I get back is the raw HTML, before JS has executed.

```
var Browser = require('zombie');
var browser = new Browser();

browser.visit('http://localhost:8080', function() {
    console.log( browser.html() )
});
```

This is an angular site so I am seeing a lot of {{data}} everywhere. Is there something I am missing to accomplish this? The site I am requesting runs from a node server, with HTML5 Mode set up like:

```
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));

//forward missing routes to index
app.all('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/index.html');
});
```

Comment: does this help? browser.wait('5s', () => {console.log(browser.html())})